# What's up with TI TIVA's SPI controller?

Tags: spi, texas-instruments

UPDATE: The issue with debugging someone else's code is you just have to assume everything is being coded correctly. I just checked datasheet and there was this BSY (bus busy) flag bit in status register. I just made it so that it waits for BSY bit to get reset and now the ~CS behaves properly. Sorry.

Working on TIVA-C 123GH6PM. Sending data over SPI lines does not produce the desired result. I am sending 3 bytes of data in one ~CS cycle and using the Freescale frame format. The ~CS line goes high before sending the last byte.
[image]

If I send 2 bytes of data, the same thing occurs - the last ~CS goes high before I have the 8 clock cycles.

The only workaround I found was adding some delay before pulling ~CS high or sending another byte of data which of course doesn't get sent.

This is my write subroutine :

```
void SPI_write(uint8_t data)
{
    *(__IO uint8_t *)&SSI2->DR = (uint8_t)data;
    while((SSI2->SR & (1<<0))==0);
}
```

I tried type casting as you see above as I have worked on STM32 before and that has data packing, and typecasting there pulls ~CS properly, just as a last ditch effort.

Why does the ~CS line behave so strange? Is there a proper solution to solve this?

PS: I have selected the data size to be 8 bits just in case that comes out as a suspicion. If the full code is needed, I shall update the post with it,, just let me know

Comment: Can you also post a scope trace of the data?

Comment: What is the name of the flag bit you're checking in `SSI2->SR & (1<<0)`?

Comment: Are you using SSInFss generated by the SSI controller for ~CS, or are you generating your ~CS in software with a GPIO write?

Comment: @crj11 I am generating my own GPIO write based ~CS as I wish to control when I send data. My slave device requires me to send 3 bytes of data in a single ~CS cycle. I have switched off alternate function mode on that particular pin too.

Comment: @brhans Checking if Transmit FIFO bit is empty. 1 = empty, 0 = not empty. It was to make sure all bits are transferred, and yet ~CS line forces the slave to not recognize that last byte of data.

Comment: It seems likely that the problem is the delay between when the data is removed from the FIFO and when it actually gets serialized.  That is why it would be best to let the controller generate the ~CS.  Either that or you are stuck adding a delay.